# Getting error while retrieving data from a sub query and using that data source in another sub query above that

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

```
select id,proc_name,p_date,p_no,p_count
from (
       (Select id,proc_name,p_date,p_no from aa) x 
          join
       (select id,count(p_no) p_count from aa group by mrn) y 
          on x.id=y.id 
     ) a 
FROM (select id,proc_name,p_date,p_no from zz) aa
```

getting the error code 42601 at the position of `FROM` (in upper case).

Comment: Counting the parentheses, there are two `FROM` clauses in your main query.

Answer (score 0):

A `SELECT` statement can only have one `FROM` clause.

Instead of using multiple `FROM` clauses, you should `JOIN` the tables.

There is no need to have two `SELECT`s from table `aa`, you can do that with a single `SELECT` using [*window functions*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
SELECT id, proc_name, p_date, p_no,
       count(p_no) OVER (PARTITION BY mrn) p_count
FROM aa;
```

You didn't tell over which columns you want to join `aa` and `zz`, but your statement could look something like this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.proc_name, a.p_date, a.p_no, a.p_count
FROM
   (SELECT id, proc_name, p_date, p_no,
           count(p_no) OVER (PARTITION BY mrn) p_count
    FROM aa) a
   JOIN zz
      ON <join condition for a and zz>;
```

Comment: yes i got that but how to use that data source ''aa'' to be used in the sub queries which are in the join ?

Comment: i want all the columns with an aggregated columns like id,proc_name,p_date,p_no and p_count(aggregated one) from a data source.i dont want to use the aa data source i.e "select id,proc_name,p_date,p_no from zz" both times in "x" and "y"  @Laurenz Albe

Comment: I have updated the answer. Does that make sense to you?